# Protractor how to wait until browser.get to a url

Tags: selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

```
    await browser.wait(function() {
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
          return `cars/detail.aspx${browser.baseUrl}`;
        });
      }, 5000, "url err");
```

How do I make protractor wait until cars/detail.aspx${browser.baseUrl} is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `urlContains` expected condition in protractor to wait until the url contains something specific. You can refer to the documentation [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.urlContains).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method, maybe it will be helpful

```
export function waitForUrlContains(url: string, customTimeout: number = E2E_TIMEOUT) {
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(myUrl => {
      return browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.urlContains(url), customTimeout, `URL do not contain: ${url}, and is: ${myUrl}`);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the Protractor's API documentation for further information on different ways of waiting for an element (url in this case) https://www.protractortest.org/#/api
You have 2 ways actually:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const myUrl = 'cars/detail.aspx${browser.baseUrl}';
```

then:

```
return browser.wait(EC.urlIs(myUrl));
```

OR

```
return browser.wait(EC.urlContains(myUrl));
```